# overlapping nav bar css

Tags: html, css

i have created a nav bar that i am using with a slightly edited web forms template (Currently learning asp etc). On some of my pages my nav bar will overlap the content of the page when trying to access through a drop down menu.
here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

here is my `site.css` file:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}


.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}


input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="select"] {
    max-width: 280px;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .jumbotron {
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);

    }
}

li {
    border-right: 1px solid #ff6600;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #2B3533;
    border: 1px solid #ff6600;
}

    ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        background: #2B3533;
    }

li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
}

li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
    float: none;
}

li:hover a {
    background: #2B3533;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #ff6600;
}

.main-navigation li ul li {
    border-top: 0;


}

ul li a:hover {
    background: #ff6600;
}

ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;


}

ul:before,
ul:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.main-navigation > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
 }

.shadowing {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.shadowing {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is my masterpage code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SyntherMaster.Master.cs" Inherits="ComputingProjectwh.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <ul class="main-navigation">
            <li><a href="/Home.aspx">Synther Physics</a></li>
            <li><a href="/RevisionTopicList.aspx">Revision by Topic</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/RevisionPages/1. Further Mechanics/Further Mechanics Topic List.aspx">Further Mechanics</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/1. Further Mechanics/Moments and Energy.aspx">Moments and Energy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/1. Further Mechanics/Motion in a Circle.aspx">Motion in a Circle</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/RevisionPages/2. Gravitaional Fields/Universal Gravitation.aspx">Gravitaional Fields</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/2. Gravitaional Fields/Universal Gravitation.aspx">Universal Gravitation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/RevisionPages/3. Electric and Magnetic Fields/Electric and Magnetic Fields Topic List.aspx">Electric and Magnetic Fields</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/3. Electric and Magnetic Fields/Capacitance.aspx">Capacitance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/3. Electric and Magnetic Fields/Electric Fields.aspx">Electric Fields</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/3. Electric and Magnetic Fields/Magnetic Fields.aspx">Magnetic Fields</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/RevisionPages/4. Nuclear and Particle Physics/Nuclear and Particle Physics Topic List.aspx">Nuclear and Particle Physics</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/4. Nuclear and Particle Physics/Electrons and Nuceli.aspx">Electrons and Nuclei</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/4. Nuclear and Particle Physics/Particle Physics.aspx">Particle Physics</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/RevisionPages/5. Nuclear Radiation/Nuclear Decay.aspx">Nuclear Radiation</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/5. Nuclear Radiation/Nuclear Decay.aspx">Nuclear Decay</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/RevisionPages/6. Thermodynamics/Thermodynamics Topic List.aspx">Thermodynamics</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/6. Thermodynamics/Gas Laws and Kinetic Theory.aspx">Gas Laws and Kinetic Theory</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/6. Thermodynamics/Internal Energy, Absolute Zero and Change of State.aspx">Internal Energy, Absolute Zero and Change of State</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/6. Thermodynamics/Specific Heat Capacity.aspx">Specific Heat Capacity</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/RevisionPages/7. Space/Space Topic List.aspx">Space</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/7. Space/Astrophysics.aspx">Astrophysics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/7. Space/Cosmology.aspx">Cosmology</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/RevisionPages/8. Oscillations/Oscillations.aspx">Oscillations</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/RevisionPages/8. Oscillations/Oscillations.aspx">Oscillations</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/RevisionTestList.aspx">Tests by Topic</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/TestPages/1. Further Mechanics/Further Mechanics Test List.aspx">Further Mechanics</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/1. Further Mechanics/Moments and Energy Test.aspx">Moments and Energy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/1. Further Mechanics/Motion in a Circle Test.aspx">Motion in a Circle</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/TestPages/2. Gravitaional Fields/Universal Gravitation Test.aspx">Gravitaional Fields</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/2. Gravitaional Fields/Universal Gravitation Test.aspx">Universal Gravitation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/TestPages/3. Electric and Magnetic Fields/Electric and Magnetic Fields Test List.aspx">Electric and Magnetic Fields</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/3. Electric and Magnetic Fields/Capacitance Test.aspx">Capacitance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/3. Electric and Magnetic Fields/Electric Fields Test.aspx">Electric Fields</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/3. Electric and Magnetic Fields/Magnetic Fields Test.aspx">Magnetic Fields</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/TestPages/4. Nuclear and Particle Physics/Nuclear and Particle Physics Test List.aspx">Nuclear and Particle Physics</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/4. Nuclear and Particle Physics/Electrons and Nuceli Test.aspx">Electrons and Nuclei</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/4. Nuclear and Particle Physics/Particle Physics Test.aspx">Particle Physics</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/TestPages/5. Nuclear Radiation/Nuclear Decay Test.aspx">Nuclear Radiation</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/5. Nuclear Radiation/Nuclear Decay Test.aspx">Nuclear Decay</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/TestPages/6. Thermodynamics/Thermodynamics Test List.aspx">Thermodynamics</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/6. Thermodynamics/Gas Laws and Kinetic Theory Test.aspx">Gas Laws and Kinetic Theory</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/6. Thermodynamics/Internal Energy, Absolute Zero and Change of State.aspx">Internal Energy, Absolute Zero and Change of State</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/6. Thermodynamics/Specific Heat Capacity.aspx">Specific Heat Capacity</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/TestPages/7. Space/Space Test List.aspx">Space</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/7. Space/Astrophysics Test.aspx">Astrophysics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/7. Space/Cosmology.aspx">Cosmology</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/TestPages/8. Oscillations/Oscillations Test.aspx">Oscillations</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/TestPages/8. Oscillations/Oscillations Test.aspx">Oscillations</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/Formula Analysis.aspx">Formula Analysis</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Sylabus Breakdown.aspx">Sylabus Breakdown</a></li>
            <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                <AnonymousTemplate> 
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %>!</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Synther Physics</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into Z-index?

Comment: yeah ive tried adding z index and position: relative to all of my nav bar classes and it still occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `position: relative;` and a `z-index` on your dropdown menu container

```
.main-navigation {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    ...
}
```

Comment: on all of them?

Comment: I just put z-index: 2; into all of the menu css files and it is still happening

Comment: just added position: relative too and still not working

Comment: Just a note, I'd suggest putting it on the actual submenu dropdowns (as well as at 999+), not the entire menu container. Reason, potential for the submenu z-i not being high enough and/or the menu bar z-i being too high.